# pytorch nn.Sequential(*list) TypeError: list is not a Module subclass

Tags: python, pytorch

when I use pytorch to train a model, I tried to print the whole net structure

so I packed all the layers in a list
then I use `nn.Sequential(*list)`

but it doesn't work, and the TypeError: list is not a Module subclass

Comment: Please provide more details of the whole context in order to increase the chances of getting a good answer

Comment: You need to use torch.nn.Module as args, and you can't use a list either (you need to pass unpacked values, one by one)

Comment: @crissal the star operator unpacks the list and pass it one by one... it is supposed to work... the error is hidden elsewhere in the code that the OP did not provide

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please provide the list of layers that you have created, are you sure you haven' done any error in that. Try checking if your list is actually [] and not [[..]]. The other thing that I noticed is that you have `list` as a variable name, which isn't a good idea - `list` is a Python keyword.

I tried writing a sample code of unpacking a list and it works fine for me.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn                                                                           net = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(2, 2), nn.Linear(2, 2))                                           
layers = [nn.Linear(2, 2), nn.Linear(2, 2)]                                                  
net = nn.Sequential(*layers)
print(net)
```

This ran without any error, and the result was:

```
Sequential(
  (0): Linear(in_features=2, out_features=2, bias=True)
  (1): Linear(in_features=2, out_features=2, bias=True)
)
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: Hopefully the `*list` was just for the sake of the example, which I agree was a bad choice anyway :)

Comment: No, it is not. Try it yourself and you'll see that it would have worked, even if you choose `list` as the variable name, which you well pointed one should not. The only reason that error is thrown is if `list=[[...]]`. Try with `list=[nn.Module()]` and you'll see it works. `list` is not a keyword, it is a type.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks for checking that. Also, the other point that you made about [[..]] seems to be the most plausible cause for this error to me as well. The author of the question might have mistakenly wrapped it twice.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I check the code and find that I did use the list=[[..][..]] by mistake.

Comment: Glad @ElevenFlogs that you found the answer helpful, if possible please upvote or accept the solution. Thanks. :)

Comment: I am willing to do that but I only have 1 reputation, for upvoting any soluton 15 reputations or more are needed

Comment: I understand, not a problem, I hope it helped for you. I guess, you must be able to accept the answer if not up-vote. Thanks.